# Android things connected with eth0 and Wlan0 but fail to install apk

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am trying to install apk first time on Raspberry Pi 3 board which have installed flashed .zip downloaded from android things console with empty bundle.

Now i am able to connect my device using wifi IP address assign to board .

So i connect it like :

```
adb connect 10.xxx.x.xxx:5555 
connected to 10.xxx.x.xxx:5555
```

Now i am trying to install apk:

```
adb install D:\Project\xxx\xxx\app\build\outputs\
things_V01.apk
Failed to install D:\Project\xxx\xxx\app\build\outputs\
things_V01.apk
```

What could be issue here.

Below is my gradle of app .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.4.1-devpreview'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Also noted that after adb install command it take much time for apk size withing 1.50MB apk .

Comment: Are you executing that command including the newline in the path?

Comment: Also, does the app already exist, but signed differently?

Comment: @AlexT. No i don't think that it's new line is just due to size of cmd in windows.

Comment: @AlexT. i also observer that some  once i connect to device with adb connect it loss connection

Answer (score 1):

As a sanity check, have you tried to interact with the device using another adb command such as **adb **?